# SQL Server - what is the size of my database if this is the output from sp_spaceused

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, size

I ran the command:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

The output was:
[image]

So what is the size of my database?
Is it - 4768.25 - 4076.57 = 691.68 MB (1st table)

OR

19896 KB (2nd table)?

**EDIT**

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express which has a "database size" limit of 4 GB. So in this context of "database size", if I were to calculate how far up to the space limit I am - I should consider the unallocated space as what my database can still use?

Comment: Define what you mean with database size? The answer in the first columns is clear - your database is 4768,25mb large. That the space is mostly unused does not mean SQL Server  does ot block it on disc.

Answer (score 2):

Your database size is 4768.25MB

SQL Server will allocate a database file bigger than the currently used space. This unallocated space is filled up until the database file needs to be 'grown' again

Comment: +1 ...Just to add a bit to this - database_size ie. 4768.25 will always be larger than the sum of reserved + unallocated space because it includes the size of log files, but reserved and unallocated_space consider only data pages.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express which has a "database size" limit of 4 GB. So in this context of "database size", if I were to calculate how far up to the space limit I am - I should consider the unallocated space as what my database can still use?

Comment: and by the way, what is the 19.896 MB part?

Answer (score 1):

To just add on to Mitch's answer in response to the edit you have posted :-

Unallocated space is the space that is not yet allocated to any database objects.

So, yes, i would consider 4076.57 MB as the space that your current database with total size of 4768.25 still has available for its use.

However, do note that this space is not just for your actual data. This space includes any and all space used by ANY database object like data,index,IAM (Index Allocation Map) pages, GAM (Global Allocation Map) pages, SGAM (Shared Global Allocation Map), or PFS (Page Free Space) pages